# populate combobox in form_load but trigger SelectedValueChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I would like to populate some key/values from  a datatable into a combobox when form is loaded. And expect that when a user make selection on the combobox, some statements are executed in the SelectedValueChanged event.

However, when I populate data using follows:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DropDownStyle =  ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "A1");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "A2");
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";   
    }
```

with following SelectedValueChanged event:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FOO");

    }
```

Once the program runs, the "foo" message box is shown twice unexpectedly, before a user can choose anything.

What is the problem?

Thx

Comment: As you add items to the `ComboBox` it is firing the event most likely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is by design, when your combobox is updated with new item, the `SelectedValue` of it is changed by design. To prevent this, you can use some kind of flag like this:

```
private bool init;
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DropDownStyle =  ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(1, "A1");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "A2");
    init = true;
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";   
    init = false;
}
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!init) MessageBox.Show("FOO");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead through designer, register your event handler after you filled the `ComboBox` at the end of the `Form_Load` event handler:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DropDownStyle =  ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(1, "A1");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "A2");
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
    comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ADDED TO KINGKING'S ANSWER ..**

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(init) Return;

    //codes here
}
```